# Keystore from digital signature e-token using java

Tags: digital-signature, e-token

How to create the keystore from digital signature e-token? How crate the path of keystore? How to sign with the keystore in any document using java application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cryptographic hardware devices can usually be interfaced via PKCS#11 API. You will need PKCS#11 library (.dll on Windows or .so on Unix) acting as a "device driver" which gets usually installed along with the software provided by the device vendor (consult your e-token documentation for the exact library location). You have mentioned "keystore" in your question therefore I guess you are using JAVA language and you can use SunPKCS11 provider to access PKCS#11 compatible cryptographic store. Here is the quick sample:

```java
// Create instance of SunPKCS11 provider
String pkcs11Config = "name=eToken\nlibrary=C:\\path\\to\\your\\pkcs11.dll";
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream pkcs11ConfigStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigStream);
java.security.Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);

// Get provider KeyStore and login with PIN
String pin = "11111111";
java.security.KeyStore keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", providerPKCS11);
keyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());

// Enumerate items (certificates and private keys) in the KeyStore
java.util.Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases();
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    System.out.println(alias);
}
```

Comment: @aich.pom if my answer helped you to resolve your question please mark it as an accepted answer. You will receive a badge and start your stackoverflow career :)

Comment: Can you tell me the same answer for java 1.4??@jariq