# etoken unaccessible after reading

Tags: java, pkcs#11, e-token

I´m trying to read out the certificate of an etoken. I´ve followed the answer from [Keystore from digital signature e-token using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283112/keystore-from-digital-signature-e-token-using-java?answertab=oldest#tab-top). It´s giving me the certificates installed in the token but after that the token isn´t reachable anymore. Did somebody got something similar while accessing a token?

```
// Create instance of SunPKCS11 provider 
String pkcs11Config = "name=eToken\nlibrary=C:\\path\\to\\your\\pkcs11.dll"; 
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream pkcs11ConfigStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes()); 
sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigStream); 
java.security.Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);  // Get provider KeyStore and login with PIN String pin = "11111111"; 
java.security.KeyStore keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", providerPKCS11); 
keyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());  // Enumerate items (certificates and private keys) in the KeyStore 
java.util.Enumeration<String> aliases = keyStore.aliases(); 
while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    System.out.println(alias); 
}
```

The problem persists, after plugging out/in the token is reachable again, but after running the code, the token seems to be locked again. OS Win2k8 Server.

Comment: Kindly add some code.

Comment: Code is from the example in the link

Comment: What is the exception you get when trying to access the token after you retrieved the certificates?

Comment: I dont get any its like you've took it away from USB . It hanging on the load

Comment: I will retry, Token was taken off and reconnected. Trying to figure Out, WHO this happens

Comment: No reason why this happens, after plugging off an plugging in the token it´s accessible again. I only get once access to the private key and then it seems like the token ist blocked. Is there anything to do to release the token? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can´t figure out what blocks the token. System Specification as follows: JAVA 1.8/Windows Server 2008

Comment: Only thing i´ve found so far is that users asign the slot number, maybe this has do something with it?
I haven´t specified it in my first tries because it wasn´t recommended as neccessary. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2226579

Comment: Still something more, the SACTools.exe is running while i try to run the java code. Maybe there a cross reference, could it be that both processes try to get access and this locks the token out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this clear. After disconnecting other USB devices the Token responds as usual.

The Token should be plugged in to a fully powered port. Best on a separate Host- Bus.